# How exactly do we add a animated border of a div inside the div itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to display an image inside a div and when mouse hover over it the border should appear inside the div in some sort of animated manner. I have done it using animated svg and it works for large screen but have no idea of doing it for smaller screens. there must be a proper alternative to it!!

I have attempted to do it using svg lines.. for which i used four such lines and added animation on each line and triggered it while hover. What is the proper way please. [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hofstadter-43z6ud?file=/src/styles.css)  link of what i have done till now.  I want similar effect for variable image/div sizes.

Comment: hope this video will help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0V4HAYYCbU

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.